# MySQL UWP "Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: mysql, uwp

I have a MySQL 5.7.20-log server running on Windows Server 2012.

I have created two simple applications:

**1. C# Windows Forms application (.NET) using 6.10.4 Connector (NuGet package)**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestMySqlConnection();
    }

    private void TestMySqlConnection()
    {
        string dbConnectionString =
        " Data source = 192.168.0.12;" +
        " Database = rcp;" +
        " User Id = rcp;" +
        " Password = *******;" +
        " SslMode = None;";

        using (MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
        }
    }
```

This application runs without problems.

**2. Universal Windows Platform application (UWP /.NetCore) using 6.10.4 Connector (NuGet package)**

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestMySqlConnection();
    }

    private void TestMySqlConnection()
    {
        string dbConnectionString =
        " Data source = 192.168.0.12;" +
        " Database = rcp;" +
        " User Id = rcp;" +
        " Password = *******;" +
        " SslMode = None;";

        using (MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
        }
    }
```

This application does not work and throws an `Exception`.

**Exception:**

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

**InnerException:**

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to MySql database directly in UWP is a new feature which is introduced from [.NET Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md) 2.0.

For the previous Universal Windows Platform, it only supports .NET Standard 1.4.

So, that's the issue you're facing. I also can reproduce it on my side if I set my project's target version is 16299, but min version is the previous version (15063,14393 etc).

To solve this issue, you would need to make the project's target version and min version are 16299.